# Как получить токен для POST запроса из Postman

Tags: java, spring, postman

Приложение на Java.
application.yml

```
server:
  port: 9000
```

platform.properties

```
jwt.secret="......."
jwt.expiration.time=864000000
jwt.header.prefix=Bearer
jwt.header=my_token
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public Result login(@RequestBody LoginRequestDto user){
    return userService.login(user);
}
```

Из Postman пробую отправить POST запрос по адресу  http://188.130.139.104:9000/login

На вкладке Authorization выбираю
Type: Basic Auth
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполняю поля Username и Password
В результате получаю

```
Could not send request
```

Comment: Похоже опечатка, порт 900?

Comment: Да опечатка, исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Auth это про другое. Он встраивается в чейн httpSecurity как httpBasic. Простой пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication).

В вашем примере вы ждете в теле запроса LoginRequestDto. Т.е. надо заполнять не вкладку авторизации, а тело запроса POST

```
{
  "username": "user",
  "password": "paswd"
}
```

Имена полей как LoginRequestDto